# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)

Tags: java, plugin, maven

Estoy usando NetBeans y Maven dejó de compilar, aumento una clase y ya no compila, lo quito y normal, ya intenté borrando el repositorio, cambiando de JDK, JRI, incluso netbeans y nada

```html
cd D:\ASUS\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ciudadanos; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111" cmd /c "\"\"D:\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install\""
Scanning for projects...
                                                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Ciudadanos 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ Ciudadanos ---
Deleting D:\ASUS\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ciudadanos\target

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:copy (default) @ Ciudadanos ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Ciudadanos ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Ciudadanos ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 11 source files to D:\ASUS\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ciudadanos\target\classes
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4.095s
Finished at: Sat Feb 17 11:30:13 COT 2018
Final Memory: 30M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Ciudadanos: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.jaxen.FunctionContext not found -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Has probado borrando la carpeta .m2 y haciendo un maven clean install?

Comment: a .m2 me referia con repositorio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no has probado borrando la carpeta m2 y haciendo un maven clean install es probable que en tus dependencias te este faltando esto

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otra opcion es [descargar desde aquí](http://www.findjar.com/jar/org/ow2/jasmine/mapping/1.0.1/mapping-1.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar.html?all=true) la clase que te falta.

Te dejo este [link](https://gracecriollo.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/error-class-file-for-org-jaxen-functioncontext-not-found/) que hace referencia a la pagina que te mencione y [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899438/getting-error-at-spring-hibernate-maven-project) el cual es de la pagina de Stack Overflow en ingles con un problema similar al tuyo y con algunas otras alternativas.
Me avisas si te sirvió, saludos.

Comment: compila, pero ignora las clases con anotacion @ Entity, @Repository y las demas, las cuales son las que agrego

Comment: Tienes la anotacion Basepackages, EntityScan ?

Comment: consulte el dato y me falto esta linia , TY `sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.model"});`